# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of bytes exhausted when use str_get_html

Tags: php, curl, dom, html-parsing

I'm did a simple request and i get right response from `curl_exec($ch);` but when i call the static method `str_get_html` my result is always the same.

```
Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted
```

I tried increase the memory `memory_limit=2048M` but the result is the same

[image: phpinfo]

**My code:**

```
$url = "https://www.php.net";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, []);
$this->callback = HtmlDomParser::str_get_html(curl_exec($ch));
...
```

Any tips? I can use regular expression, but will be my last choice.

Comment: First is to check what size the HTML is.  You could try and use DOMDocument, but again without knowing the page size it's difficult to know if it will cater for it.

Comment: According of this website (https://sitechecker.pro/page-size/), the html size is: 38.96 KB, looks very small

Comment: Are you sure you changed the correct `php.ini` file when you tried to increase memory?

Comment: ```phpinfo();``` tell me and he doesn't lie. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think HTML DOM Parser does not clean up memory in the DOM each time file_get_html or str_get_html is called so it needs to be done explicity each time you have finished with the current DOM. This is as simple as adding `->clear()` at the end of a loop or when you’ve finished using it.

Comment: I also did that, but doesn't work.   ```$dom->clear();  unset($dom);```